# Не работает метод clear()

Tags: python, tkinter, clear

Вот есть такой код:

```
import time
import os

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Sys.tem")

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

window_width = 350
window_height = 200
x = (screen_width // 2) - (window_width // 2)
y = (screen_height // 2) - (window_height // 2)
root.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")

text = ""

def func1(event):
    global text
    text += event.char
    if event.keysym == "Return":
        print(text)
        text = ""

    elif event.keysym == "End":
        print(f"{text}", end='')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('\r', end='')
    
    elif event.keysym == "Prior":
        clear()



root.bind("<KeyPress>", func1)

root.mainloop()
```

И при нажатии клавиши `Prior (PgUp)` консоль должна очищаться методом `clear()`. Но почему то этого не происходит. Подскажите, в чем проблема или чем можно заменить данную функцию?

Comment: А операционная система какая? 
    `os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')`

Comment: @Amgarak, Windows 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот код для очистки консоли в разных операционных системах

```
def clear_console():
    if os.name == 'nt':
        os.system('cls')
    else:
        os.system('clear')
```

И запускать в Вашем коде
…

```
elif event.keysym == "Prior":
    clear_console()
```